# Problema mostrando los datos en una JTable

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo el siguiente problema, estaba desarrollando un código que hiciera unos cálculos con distribuciones y números aleatorios que luego se pasarían a una tabla en otra vista que mostraría los resultados de las n repeticiones del cálculo, pero cuando reviso los resultados de la tabla, veo que esta repitiendo los mismos valores la cantidad de veces que debe repetir los calculos, revise que no estuviera obteniendo el mismo resultado siempre y todo esta correcto, asi que mi problema esta en la forma de enviar y/o imprimir los datos en la tabla.

El código del cálculo es este:

```
Cant_Rep = Integer.parseInt(Repeticiones.getText());
        Hec_Tot = 3;
        Kil_Hec = 9000;
        Porc_Ferm = new dist_Uniforme(60,70);
        Porc_Sobr = new dist_Uniforme(0,20);
        Porc_Desc = new dist_Normal(3.575,18.0625);
        Lit = 750;
        Costo_Fijo = 15600;
        Costo_Jov = 2.10;
        Costo_Añe = 7.10;
        Costo_Esp = 3.10;
        Precio_Jov = 95;
        Precio_Añe = 450;
        Precio_Esp = 120;
        Demanda_Jov = new dist_Triangular(9000,11000,11800);
        Demanda_Añe = new dist_Triangular(2100,2500,4100);
        Demanda_Esp = new dist_Normal(0.81,0.661);

        Hec_Util = 3;
        Tiem_Ferm = 8;
        Porc_Cons = 60;

        vr = new vent_resultado();
        vr.setVisible(true);

        int $i = 0;

        while($i<=Cant_Rep)
        {                
            double ps = Porc_Sobr.generarDU();
            double pf = Porc_Ferm.generarDU();
            double pd = Porc_Desc.generarDN();
            Viñedo = (Kil_Hec * Hec_Util) * (ps * 0.01);
            Descarte = Viñedo * (pd * 0.01);
            Seleccion = Viñedo - Descarte;
            Fermentado = Seleccion * (pf * 0.01) * Tiem_Ferm;    
            Ferm_Espum = Seleccion * (pf * 0.01) * (Tiem_Ferm * 2);
            Maduracion = Fermentado * (Lit * 0.01);
            Mad_Espum = Ferm_Espum * (Lit * 0.01);
            Vinos_Jov = Maduracion;
            Vinos_Añe = Maduracion * (Porc_Cons * 0.01);
            Vinos_Esp = Mad_Espum * (Porc_Cons * 0.01);

            double de = Demanda_Esp.generarDN();
            double dj = Demanda_Jov.generarDT();
            double da = Demanda_Añe.generarDT();
            Ing_Jov = Vinos_Jov * Precio_Jov * dj;
            Ing_Añe = Vinos_Añe * Precio_Añe * da;
            Ing_Esp = Vinos_Esp * Precio_Esp * de;
            Ing_Totales = Ing_Jov + Ing_Añe + Ing_Esp;
            Gastos_Jov = Vinos_Jov * Costo_Jov;
            Gastos_Añe = Vinos_Añe * Costo_Añe;
            Gastos_Esp = Vinos_Esp * Costo_Esp;
            Gastos_Tot = Gastos_Jov + Gastos_Añe + Gastos_Esp + Costo_Fijo;
            Ganan_Jov = Ing_Jov - Gastos_Jov;
            Ganan_Añe = Ing_Añe - Gastos_Añe;
            Ganan_Esp = Ing_Esp - Gastos_Esp;
            Ganan_Tot = Ing_Totales - Gastos_Tot;

            vr.mostrarDatos(Viñedo,Descarte,Seleccion,Fermentado,Ferm_Espum,Maduracion,Mad_Espum,Vinos_Jov,Vinos_Añe,Vinos_Esp,Ing_Jov,Ing_Añe,Ing_Esp,Ing_Totales,Gastos_Jov,Gastos_Añe,Gastos_Esp,Gastos_Tot,Ganan_Jov,Ganan_Añe,Ganan_Esp,Ganan_Tot,Cant_Rep);
            $i++;
        }
        this.dispose();
```

Y el de la tabla es este:

```
public void mostrarDatos(double viñe,double desc,double sele,double fer,double fer_esp,double mad,double mad_esp,double vin_jov,double vin_añe,double vin_esp,double ing_jov,double ing_añe,double ing_esp,double ing_tot,double gas_jov,double gas_añe,double gas_esp,double gas_tot,double gan_jov,double gan_añe,double gan_esp,double gan_tot, int cant_rep){

    int con = 0;
    String data [][] = {};
    String col[] = {"#","Viñedo","Descarte","Seleccion","Fermentado","Ferm_Espum","Maduracion","Mad_Espum","Vinos_Jov","Vinos_Añe","Vinos_Esp","Ing_Jov","Ing_Añe","Ing_Esp","Ing_Totales","Gastos_Jov","Gastos_Añe","Gastos_Esp","Gastos_Tot","Ganan_Jov","Ganan_Añe","Ganan_Esp","Ganan_Tot"};
    mtabla = new DefaultTableModel(data,col);
    Datos.setModel(mtabla);

    int $i = 1;
    while ($i<=cant_rep)
    {
        mtabla.insertRow(con, new Object[]{});
        mtabla.setValueAt($i, con, 0);
        mtabla.setValueAt(viñe, con, 1);
        mtabla.setValueAt(desc, con, 2);
        mtabla.setValueAt(sele, con, 3);
        mtabla.setValueAt(fer, con, 4);
        mtabla.setValueAt(fer_esp, con, 5);
        mtabla.setValueAt(mad, con, 6);
        mtabla.setValueAt(mad_esp, con, 7);
        mtabla.setValueAt(vin_jov, con, 8);
        mtabla.setValueAt(vin_añe, con, 9);
        mtabla.setValueAt(vin_esp, con, 10);
        mtabla.setValueAt(ing_jov, con, 11);
        mtabla.setValueAt(ing_añe, con, 12);
        mtabla.setValueAt(ing_esp, con, 13);
        mtabla.setValueAt(ing_tot, con, 14);
        mtabla.setValueAt(gas_jov, con, 15);
        mtabla.setValueAt(gas_añe, con, 16);
        mtabla.setValueAt(gas_esp, con, 17);
        mtabla.setValueAt(gas_tot, con, 18);
        mtabla.setValueAt(gan_jov, con, 19);
        mtabla.setValueAt(gan_añe, con, 20);
        mtabla.setValueAt(gan_esp, con, 21);
        mtabla.setValueAt(gan_tot, con, 22);
        $i++;
        con++;
    }
}
```

No he podido averiguar donde me he equivocado, espero puedan explicarme que hice mal.

Answer (score 0):

Creo ver un fallo en la creación de la tabla, al no poder compilarlo entero prueba a realizar esto al cargar los datos.(Codigo abajo)

-Para empezar necesitas tener creado un JTable en este caso lo llamaremos resultado.
-Ahora coges tu DefaultTableModel y le asignas el model de resultado con getModel()
-Ahora ya añadiremos cada fila con la orden addRow de mtabla, creando un nuevo array de objetos que incluya el dato para cada columna.

```
javax.swing.JTable resultados;
resultados = new javax.swing.JTable();
resultados.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel (
new Object[][] {},
new String[] {"#","Viñedo","Descarte","Seleccion","Fermentado","Ferm_Espum","Maduracion","Mad_Espum","Vinos_Jov","Vinos_Añe","Vinos_Esp","Ing_Jov","Ing_Añe","Ing_Esp","Ing_Totales","Gastos_Jov","Gastos_Añe","Gastos_Esp","Gastos_Tot","Ganan_Jov","Ganan_Añe","Ganan_Esp","Ganan_Tot"}
    ) {
        Class[] types = new Class [] {
            java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Float.class, java.lang.String.class
        };
        boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
            /*SI DESEAS EDITAR CAMPOS DIRECTAMENTE, PON LAS OPCIONES, EN EL MISMO ORDEN QUE EN EL STRING[] CON TRUE*/
            false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false
        };

        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return types [columnIndex];
        }

        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return canEdit [columnIndex];
        }
    });
/*HASTA AQUI HEMOS CREADO LA TABLA CON SUS COLUMNAS Y EL MODELO CON EL ORDEN DE DATOS*/
/*AHORA CREAREMOS OPCIONALMENTE UN SCROLL PANE PARA QUE SE PUEDAN MOVER POR LOS DATOS*/
javax.swing.JScrollPanel panel;
panel = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
panel.setViewportView(resultados);

/*AHORA INCLUIREMOS LOS DATOS, CAMBIANDO TU WHILE POR UN FOR QUE ES MAS UTIL Y INCLUYENDOLOS CON LA VARIABLE MTABLA*/
mtabla = (DefaultTableModel) resultados.getModel();
for(int i = 1; i <= cant_rep; i++){
    mtabla.addRow(new Object[] {i, viñe, desc, sele, fer, fer_esp, mas, mas_esp, vin_jov, vin_añe, vin_esp, ing_tot, gas_jov, gas_añe, gas_esp, gas_tot, gan_añe, gan_jov, gan_esp, gan_tot});
}
/*Y ASI SE AÑADIRIA CADA DATO*/
```

De la misma manera que cambiamos el while por un for deberías hacerlo en la otra clase. Prueba eso y comprueba si te funciona. Cualquier cosa me dices, un saludo

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me ayudo a entender que estaba fallando, no fue la solucion en si pero me ayudo bastante